# Delete chapter numbering

Tags: table-of-contents

I am working on my research and using a \documentclass{report}. How can I cancel the chapter  numbering as in the picture.
[image]

And the numbering began from  section.

Comment: Do you want to remove the chapter number  from the table of contents alone, or also from the chapter head?

Comment: Do you refer to the chapter number itself or to the page number that corresponds to the chapter? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to remove the chapter number from the table of contents and the page number as in the picture

Comment: Is the section numbering continuous or start again for each chapter?